# ArrayList Size Increasing every onCreateView call

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, arraylist

I have `RecyclerView` in `Fragment` and I am populating `ArrayList` from `Sqlite` and there is a `Form` which lets me add the entries into database. So what would've gone wrong?

It works fine until I add any new entries,but when I add new entries via the form, it redirects back to the `RecyclerView's Fragment`, without showing any newly added entries. When I again press button to add entries and come back without adding any entry into form by pressing **back button** it shows new entries and also makes a copy of the previous entries. I don't know where I am going wrong, and I've already tried things to resolve but couldn't get through this.

Here is my `fragment` where I have `RecyclerView`

```
public class fragment_1 extends Fragment {

    CRUD_database db;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    static List<PPL_list_wrapper> Loc_details=new ArrayList<PPL_list_wrapper>();
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    PPL_list_wrapper PPL_wrapper;
    int ID;
    ArrayList<PPL_list_wrapper> list=new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String TAG="====Fragment_1====";
    String name,title,address,passing_year,description;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);
        TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listNULL);
        mRecyclerView= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.ppl_RecyclerView);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter=new ppl_Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(),list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        fab= (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.PPL_fab_Add_PPL);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                Add_PPL add_ppl=new Add_PPL(); //This Fragment Has Form To Add Entry into Database
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout,add_ppl);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG,"Value of Context Oncreate "+" Value of GetActivity"+" "+getActivity());
        db=new CRUD_database(getActivity());
        Cursor cursor=db.getALL_PPL();
            Log.d(TAG,"Cursor Position To First :"+cursor.moveToFirst());
            Log.d(TAG,"Cursor and List Value :"+"Cursor: "+cursor.getCount()+" "+"List: "+list.size());
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()&& !(list.size()==cursor.getCount())){   // This Condition to avoid Array to increase its size as soon as database has new row it will call 
               do{

                        Log.d(TAG,"Cursor Position: "+cursor.getColumnCount()+" "+"Value of Rows "+cursor.getCount());
                        ID=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));
                        name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PPL_NAME"));
                        title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PPL_TITLE"));
                        address=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PPL_ADDRESS"));
                        passing_year=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PPL_TIME"));
                        description=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PPL_DESCRIPTION"));

                        Log.d(TAG,title+" "+address+" "+ passing_year+" "+description+" "+ID);
                        PPL_list_wrapper fromDatabase=new PPL_list_wrapper(ID,title,name,passing_year,address);
                        list.add(fromDatabase);
                        adapter=new ppl_Recycler_Adapter(getActivity(),list);
                       // adapter.notifyItemChanged(cursor.getCount());

                }
               while (cursor.moveToNext());
                adapter.notifyItemChanged(cursor.getCount());
                cursor.close();
            }
        else if (cursor.getColumnCount()==0 || list.size()==0){
                textView.setText("NO RECORD FOUND");
            }

        return view;
    }
```

So my question is that how can I avoid `Arraylist` in order to increase its size after coming back to `RecyclerView Fragment` from form `Fragment`?

And how can I get complete rows from database whenever `RecyclerView Fragment's onCreateView` is called every time.

Comment: you did not add list.clear() thats why duplicacy is there

Comment: call it in `onCreate()`

Comment: list=new ArrayList<>(); add this line just before your getting all data from DB

Comment: Clear your arraylist out of _do.....while_ loop before adding it to arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
list.clear();
```

after getting **cursor** from db.

Comment: Is it best way to populate list cuz it will call everytime RecyclerView Fragment calls (onCreateView)
First List will clear then get entries back to it.Can i only add single entry (New entry ) which is just added by form

Comment: yeah. You can test it.

Comment: Thx it helps but still one question in my mind would its a best way to populate arraylist cuz clear and add will call multiple times in every onCreateView

Comment: yeah. This is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize in **OnCreateView**

```
list=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: it will create new arraylist whenever Fragment's onCreateView is call every time.